# Taking player input

Tags: c++

I need help on how to allowing player to input a number in this code:

```
    using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char name[50];
    menu:
    cout << "Select your choice..." << endl;
    cout << "1) Start Game" << endl;
    cout << "2) Help" << endl;
    cout << "3) Exit Game" << endl;
    cin.getline(number, 1);
    if(number = 1) {
        start_game();
    }
    else if(number = 2){
        help();
    }
    else if(number = 3){
        exit();
    }
    else {
        goto menu;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It says that there is a problem in the cin.getline(number,1) in my program. If anyone knows how to fix it, please tell me. Thanks

Comment: use ``==`` for comparison, not ``=``

Comment: `number = 1` is an assignment, `number == 1` is a comparison

Comment: Also don't use `goto`! A simple loop is a way better solution

Comment: `number == 1` is comparing a string against a number.  `number == "1"` is comparing a string against a string literal, which will do what you want.  And use a `std::string number` instead of a char array.  Or use `int number` and `cin >> number`.

Comment: `number` is not declared, and `number == "1"` (if `number` were an`char` array) would be comparing a couple of memory addresses, no strings or strings of `char` s involved.

Comment: I think you should find a good book or tutorial and learn the basic concepts.

Comment: read compiler warnings!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char name[50];
    while (true) // Use a loop instead of goto since it is more readable for other developers
    {
        cout << "Select your choice..." << endl;
        cout << "1) Start Game" << endl;
        cout << "2) Help" << endl;
        cout << "3) Exit Game" << endl;
        int number; // You didn't declare `number`
        cin >> number; // You used getline wrong
        if (number == 1) { // Use `==` for comparing
            start_game();
            break;
        }
        if (number == 2) {
            help();
            break;
        }
        if (number == 3) {
            exit();
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I explained some fixes in the comments.

Comment: Same but decided to make the flow the same as in the question.

Comment: Please don't answer when the solution is a simple error like this. Put the answer in a comment and flag to close for ot:simple typographical error

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 
int main()
{
     char name[50];
     int number ; 
     menu: 
     cout << "Select your choice..." << endl;
     cout << "1) Start Game" << endl;
     cout << "2) Help" << endl; 
     cout << "3) Exit Game" << endl;
     cin >> number;
     if(number == 1) { 
            start_game(); 
     } 
     else if(number == 2){ 
            help(); 
     } 
     else if(number == 3){ 
            exit(); 
     } 
     else { 
           goto menu; 
     } 
return 0; 
}
```